Rolling 3 Month sum is not aggregating correctly
I'm having an issue with rolling 3 month sums in databricks. I've used window function many times and have not had an issue. However, I have not done it databricks. Basically, I'm trying to calculate 3 month rolling at the lowest grain and create a table. I would expect that when I aggregate at to higher grains, say, a single dimension and date, it would give me an accurate sum. The sum should be the same as if I had only partitioned by that dim


select dateid, geography, country, data_source, source_file_name, gender_cd, universe_cd, retail_units, purchase_channel_cd, retail_dollars, total_transactions, segment_cd, age_cd,
app_class_cd, brand_cd, retailer_cd, activity_cd, item_cd,
--3 month
SUM(retail_units) OVER (PARTITION BY geography, country, data_source, source_file_name, gender_cd, universe_cd, purchase_channel_cd, retailer_type_cd, segment_cd, age_cd,
app_class_cd, brand_cd, retailer_cd, activity_cd, item_cd
ORDER BY dateid RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 MONTH preceding AND current row) as rolling_3_month_units,
SUM(retail_dollars) OVER (PARTITION BY geography, country, data_source, source_file_name, gender_cd, universe_cd, purchase_channel_cd, retailer_type_cd, segment_cd, age_cd,
app_class_cd, brand_cd, retailer_cd, activity_cd, item_cd
ORDER BY dateid RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 MONTH preceding AND current row) as rolling_3_month_dollars,
SUM(total_transactions) OVER (PARTITION BY geography, country, data_source, source_file_name, gender_cd, universe_cd, purchase_channel_cd, retailer_type_cd, segment_cd, age_cd,
app_class_cd, brand_cd, retailer_cd, activity_cd, item_cd
ORDER BY dateid RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 MONTH preceding AND current row) as rolling_3_month_transactions
from(
SELECT DISTINCT
        'APLA' AS geography,
        'JP' AS country,
        'NPD' AS data_source,
        'JSPORT_APL.tab' AS source_file_name,
        method_of_purchase AS purchase_channel_cd,
        channel AS retailer_type_cd,
        gender_of_wearer AS gender_cd,
        wearer_segment AS segment_cd,
        age_of_wearer AS age_cd,
        used_for_sport AS universe_cd,
        'NA' AS nike_segment_cd,
        'NA' AS fields_of_play_cd,
        apparel_silhouette AS app_class_cd,
        brand_client_list AS brand_cd,
        retailer_client_list AS retailer_cd,
        primary_sport_used_for AS activity_cd,
        apparel_silhouette AS item_cd,
        to_date(months, 'MMMM yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM' as dateid,
        SUM(transaction_count) AS total_transactions,
        SUM(projected_usd_value) AS retail_dollars,
        SUM(round(total_units_projected)) AS retail_units
    FROM development.market_insights.processed_jsport_apl
    WHERE active_ind = 'Y'
    GROUP BY all
    ORDER BY dateid
)
order by app_class_cd, brand_cd, retailer_cd, activity_cd, item_cd, geography, country, data_source, source_file_name, gender_cd, universe_cd, retail_units, purchase_channel_cd, retail_dollars, total_transactions, segment_cd, age_cd,
dateid



